# Is Ash technically the Pokemon Champion of Alola like Steven?

Tags: pokemon

In *Pokémon Sun Moon* anime, now that Pokémon League Champion is Ash and there are no Elite Four, does this make Ash the Pokemon Champion of Alola?

Comment: According to a [dutch newsoutlet](https://nos.nl/artikel/2301960-ash-ketchum-na-22-jaar-eindelijk-pokemon-master.html) he is now a pokemon master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Ash is now considered a Pokemon champion of Alola like Steven.
However, Ash already was a 'champion' before becoming the champion of Alola, the champion of Orange Islands.

However his victory on Orange Islands is often disregarded due to the unconventional 5 gym battles without Elite Four, a Champion, or a Conference.

As mentioned on the [Pokemon fan Wiki](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Champion) the following is required to become a champion

> A Pokémon Champion is a trainer who has beaten a region's Gym Leaders (in Alola's case, all 7 trials and totem Pokemon), Elite Four, and the previous Champion.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, He is one of the regional champions now because this was the first league of Alola region. He is now the one step closer to
>  become a Pokemon master. He will get the official invitation for the
>  next champion's league tournament where he will battle against the
>  regional champions. If he wins then he will be considered as a Pokemon
>  master by the world.

Comment: I am not asking asking whether he is pokemon master I am asking he is regional champion like Steven stone in honen.